# Would storing video files in DAOS enabled database speed up accesing them via https?

Tags: lotus-domino

We are planning to store video files (mp4 files) as part of domino documents. The files will be anything up to 800MB-1GB. The documents will be accessed via web (https). We are able to play the video when it is a part of the document but we are not able to move forward or backwards. Basically the video plays sequentially, you can only stop it or refresh the page.

When we moved the video to file resources and accessed that, the video takes a long time to start but we can move forward or backward. But the movement is not instantaneous, it takes long time as the server searches for the right start.

When we moved the video into the domino/html folder, it started immediately and we could move forward and backward instantaneously.

We do not have DAOS enabled on our server therefore I could not test. Do you know if the database was DAOS enabled could we get the same behaviour as when the video was stored in domino/html?

Additional info:
Apparently the issue is the attachments are being compressed by Huffman compression an therefore not available for byte range serving. When they are not compressed they can be byte range served and the access is much faster but is still much slower that when served from domino/html folder. Info on how to prevent an attachment from being compressed is here: [Disabling LZ1-compression for uploaded files via XPage xp:fileUpload (byte-range serving related)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739049/disabling-lz1-compression-for-uploaded-files-via-xpage-xpfileupload-byte-range)

My question reduces to: Would moving attachments to DAOS enable the Domino http server to serve the attachments faster?

Comment: Huge files should never be attached to Notes document in a database. It is not the purpose of any database manager. It makes the database big and hazardous to maintain. You should only put links to files in the documents. I can say it works, as I have experienced such a Domino app.

Comment: While I agree with you in principle, having those files in Domino makes managing access to the files really simple. Just use database ACL and readers/editor fields.

Comment: Files in DAOS do respect the ACL. 
And files on the server filesystem may also be controlled by an ACL : below Internet Documents, you may create Web Site File Protection.

Comment: I converted the database so that now it is DAOS enabled. I did not see any visible improvement in the speed of serving the file. It was the same as when the database was not DAOS enabled. Web Site File Protection would be in this instance a very complicated solution because one would have to dynamically change the access to the files. (Access has to be by userName, not by role).

Comment: Did you enable DAOS with or without encryption ? I guess that decyphering large DAOS files may slower files reading.

Comment: The database itself was not encrypted but DAOS is encrypted. So given my answer I was comparing the performance of playing the video file from the unencrypted DAOS disabled database to playing it from unencrypted DAOS enabled database (DB unencrypted but DAOS encrypted). I saw no difference. I did not test playing from unencrypted DAOS (the DAOS has to be encrypted because of other databased on the server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the database so that it is DAOS enabled. I did not do any formal measurements but just by look and feel I did not see any visible improvement in the speed of serving the file. It was the same as when the database was not DAOS enabled. Also ByteRange serving did not work

When leting Domino serve the file as a file from the file system direct, the increase of speed was noticable and ByteRange serving worked as expected and desired.

Comment: I guess that direct file transfer is a plain standard HTTP request, while requesting a file in an NSF adds the extra Notes layer - the one you praise for filtering through Readers field and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can know without trying. But my guess is: It will not differ much from the way it plays when not in DAOS: DAOS is absolutely transparent for all parts of the clients / server accessing the file. That makes me think that there will no be difference in handling attachments.

Comment: That is what I was trying to avoid. It looks like I will have to try.